# jQuery animate if class is not .active

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate the background colour of my nav which I can get to work with

```
$(".mainNav li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#EF4D23" }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#303030" }, 500);
});
```

What i want to do next is only do this animation if the class of the  tag is not .active, so I am trying:

```
$(".mainNav li a").hover(function () {
    if ($(this).not(".active")) {
        (function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#EF4D23" }, 500);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#303030" }, 500);
        });
    }
});
```

But it is not doing anything or giving me an error.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
    $(".mainNav li a").not(".active").hover(function () {
...code    
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `.is()` rather than `.not()` (`.not()` will filter the elements, `.is()` returns a boolean based on whether it matches the selector)

```
$(".mainNav li a").hover(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(".active")) {
       (function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#EF4D23" }, 500);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#303030" }, 500);
        });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> `if ($(this).not('active').length > 0) {`